# Manually Remove and Change WordPress Page/Post Title

Tags: php

I have added custom metaboxes into the wp-admin page and post editors.  There is a metabox with the ability to enter in a person's first name (ex. "John") and last name (ex. "Doe").

I want to set that particular post's/page's title to the combined values of those form entries (ex. "John Doe") without having to enter it in the top page/post title bar.  This would, thus allow the post/page to behave like a contact card.  Preferably, I would like this to work with permalinks too.

*I must include any non-native and new code into the functions.php file of my child theme **only**.*

For Reference: I am using the Genesis Framework.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The metabox could be saving info anywhere in the Database. Is this metabox something you have coded together or something that is a part of Genesis?

Comment: I have coded it myself with the help of [Bill Erickson's custom metabox](http://www.billerickson.net/wordpress-metaboxes/) post.  I am not sure where the info is being saved.  I assume it uses the add_meta_box() and add_post_meta() functions.  You might check the init.php file that is from Bill Erickson.

Answer (score 1):

Simply filter [**`the_title`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_title) to replace/append the post title with this post custom meta data.

I assume that you already know how to query your post custom meta data, and as such, that querying will be outside the scope of this answer. Let's assume that you've queried the meta data, as `$post_author_fname` and `$post_author_lname`, and that you want to *append* these names to the *beginning* of the post title:

```
<?php
function wpse53575_filter_the_title( $title ) {
    // Query post metadata here
    $post_author_fname = '';
    $post_author_lname = '';
    // Concatenate:
    $post_author name = trim( $post_author_fname . ' ' . $post_author_lname );
    // If the name is not an empty string,
    // append it to the post title
    $new_title = ( '' != $post_author_name ? $post_author_name . ': ' . $title ? $title );
    // return the result
    return $new_title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse53575_filter_the_title' );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not solve your permalinks issue, but there is a built-in filter for tweaking the titles before being displayed. It is used in the core to add the 'Protected:' or 'Private:' in the title.

Setup the filters with

```
add_filter( 'protected_title_format', 'your_title_function' );

add_filter( 'private_title_format', 'your_title_function' );
```

There is a great post that can be modified for your purposes at http://ben.lobaugh.net/blog/20041/wordpress-how-to-remove-protected-and-private-from-post-titles